# A beats B beats C beats A

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

From a competition archive (like my previous question):

> A round-robin chess tournament is held such that each team plays against each other exactly once. Each team loses 10 games and wins 10 games each; there are no draws. How many subsets $\{A,B,C\}$ are there, such that A beats B, B beats C, and C beats A?

The answer given is 385.

My attempt:

> As there are 21 teams and each wins 10 teams (or alternatively $\binom{21}2$), we have 210 subsets $\{A,B\}$ such that A beats B. Furthermore, as B also wins 10 times, we have 2100 subsets $\{A,B,C\}$ such that A beats B and B beats C. **But how do we apply C beats A?**

> C wins 10 times and loses 9 times (excluding the loss against B), so there's a roughly $\frac{10}{19}$ chance that C beats A. This gives an approximation of $\frac{10}{19}\cdot2100\approx1105$ subsets. Not taking order into account, we get $\frac{1105}3\approx368$ which is quite close. How do we get the exact value?

Comment: Was the statement that there are 21 teams part of the original question?

Comment: @JennyKenkel no, but we can know because each team won 10 games and lost 10 games

Comment: Which competition archive are these from btw? I saw your other post and they definitely seem like interesting questions.

Comment: Since this is about chess and not soccer, I'm mostly confused by the use of teams instead of players

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Not that rare.  You have a team of 3 or 5 with a captain that play extra game(s) to resolve draws.

Comment: @Bryce well, I can give you the link, but it's in my native language if you don't mind

Comment: That works @Samuel!

Comment: @Bryce alright, [here it is](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GWGnENA_XnWlRRm--X7rDljNk-m63A_v) (my two questions are from 2022, math questions have "MR" in their file name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each team played 20 games against distinct teams, there must be 21 teams. Consider any 3-subset {A,B,C} from all 21 teams. There are $\binom{21}{3} = 1330$ such subsets.

For each 3-subset, it can be the case that one team won 2 games or no team won 2 games.

For the first case, when
A beat B and A beat C, there are $\binom{10}{2} = 45$ ways to choose these 2 wins from A's 10 wins, and since this can be the case for any of the 21 teams, there are 45 * 21 = 945 total combinations. For the second case, it must be the case that A beat B, B beat C, and C beat A (since if this is not the case, then some team won 2 games, which is a contradiction). Therefore, this case has 1330 - 945 = 385 combinations since it must account for all the combinations not previously accounted for.

Comment: Right! Thank you very much